# how to have items hidden by default then shown with jquery button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a

with various screenshots to be hidden when the page is loaded, then once the button with the toggle function attached is clicked, show them. But, when the page loads they are shown by default, how can this be changed?
Thank you.

HTML:

```
<button>Screenshots</button>
    <p id="hide">Pretent these are some images yo.</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#hide").toggle('slow');
  });
});
```

Comment: please hide them in the first place with javascript as well, else people with javascript disabled will be unable to see them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the element the `display: none` declaration in your CSS. And on you click event you can give it `display: block`, to show itself.

CSS:

```
#hide {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#hide").css('display', 'block');
  });
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExmLX/)

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: The hide automatically gets toggled with the jquery toggle function.
This works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Yes, there are several ways of achieving your goal, my example is just one. As the others stated it is best practice to hide the elements via jQuery as well, so that users with no js enabled can see the elements. But sometimes it is possible that you get a delay until your hide script is processed, so hiding via CSS is faster. You could use something like modernizr or add yourself a class to your DOM to identify id the user has JS enabled and then adapt your CSS like `.no-js #hide {display: block;}` and `.js #hide {display: none}`. I hope I don't confuse you.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#element-to-hide').hide();
    $('#button-to-show').on('click', function() {
        $('#element-to-hide').toggle();
    });
})
```

**BUT:** When your page is loading, the `'#element-to-hide'` will be shown until *ready event* be fired.

Then you should use something like this:

**CSS:**

```
.hide { display: none }
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button-to-show').on('click', function() {
        $('#element-to-hide').toggleClass('hide');
    });
})
```

Using this way, you will not have troubles of element showing before end of page loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in multiple ways. The most cost-efficient is to hide them using css:

```
display: none;
```

You could also use your jQuery to hide them by default:

```
$(".hiddenClass").hide();
```

But, as Eevee stated in his comment, it is best to do this using the jQuery way, since some people might not have javascript on (although that is highly unlikely nowadays), and if they don't have it on they will not be able to see the other screenshots at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<input type="button" id="show" value="test" style="display: none;">
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#show").click(function(){
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```